# How to show quantity in opencart when someone login?

Tags: php, opencart, stock

In product page it shows - **Availability: In Stock** 
But when someone login then it will show quantity in the product page instead of **in stock**.
When I go to admin section there is option of (Display Stock: Display stock quantity on the product page.) But when I do "YES" to display stock then it show quantity to everyone generally without login. 
But I want that when someone will login then it show quantity Only to login customer.
Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

First set *Display Stock:* to **Yes** in Settings in backend.

Then edit file `catalog/controller/product/product.php`:

Find (around line number 280)

```
if ($product_info['quantity'] <= 0) {
   $this->data['stock'] = $product_info['stock_status'];
} elseif ($this->config->get('config_stock_display')) {
   $this->data['stock'] = $product_info['quantity'];
} else {
   $this->data['stock'] = $this->language->get('text_instock');
}
```

Replace with

```
if ($product_info['quantity'] <= 0) {
    $this->data['stock'] = $product_info['stock_status'];
} elseif ($this->config->get('config_stock_display') && $this->customer->isLogged()) {
    $this->data['stock'] = $product_info['quantity'];
} else {
    $this->data['stock'] = $this->language->get('text_instock');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it really worked. You guys are great...

Actually I want to show quantity to a particular only one customer group.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it really worked. You guys are great...

Actually I want to show quantity to a particular one customer group.

For example, I have 10 customer groups but I want to show quantity to only 1 customer group and rest of the 9 customer group can see only "in stock".

Comment: just replace the part $this->customer->isLogged() with $this->customer->getCustomerGroupId()==Your_customer_group_ID

Comment: Hello @Ramesh ;

I have added your codes to Opencart 2 and then my Oc gves the fallowing error messages;

Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded property ControllerProductProduct::$data has no effect in /var/www/vhosts/xxxx/eshop.mydomain.com/catalog/controller/product/product.php on line 290 

What can i do?

Comment: @ikutluay 
Hey bro In OC2 We don't user $this->data
So replace 
$this->data['stock']
with
$data['stock']
It should work fine ..
Thanks

Comment: Hi @Ramesh I have do what you proposed but im sorry that there is no getCustomerGroupId()funtions inthe all code. Maybe it is removed...

Comment: Hi @Ramesh after message i digged the code by myselft and found that that function renamed to "getGroupId()"... So now the code works... Regards